# IIF to change the value of a field in a table

Tags: reporting-services

I have a table with an int that is formatted like this 20141230 yyyyMMdd
Not every date is filled out and want to show an other message then #error when I convert the int to a datetime

`=IIF(Fields!LMEXPI.Value = "" OR IsNothing(Fields!LMEXPI.Value), "NoDate", "")`

In the true section I want to add this code

`=new DateTime(Fields!LMEXPI.Value / 10000, (Fields!LMEXPI.Value / 100) mod 100, Fields!LMEXPI.Value mod 100)`

In the First example it changes the dates that are empty with "NoDate" but when I add the 2nd code block to the IIF expression It completly shuts down and show #error on every row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to convert the int to a string to get the first condition to not throw #errors, then you should be able to use `DateSerial` to construct a date with that logic:

```
=IIF(CStr(Fields!LMEXPI.Value) = "" OR IsNothing(Fields!LMEXPI.Value), "NoDate", DateSerial(Fields!LMEXPI.Value / 10000, (Fields!LMEXPI.Value / 100) Mod 100, Fields!LMEXPI.Value Mod 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use new inline to instanstiate a values

```
=IIF(Fields!LMEXPI.Value = "" OR IsNothing(Fields!LMEXPI.Value), "NoDate", DateValue(MEXPI.Value))
```

I can't test this sorry

Comment: I used it and it does not work every field in the column is #error, I guess i have to keep looking

Comment: @LodeVlaeminck: the other answer with DateSerial is what I was going for